# Say message into 10 extensions at the same time

Tags: asterisk

I need to do the following in asterisk
I have 10 extensions 1001, 1002 .... 1010 (normal phones)

I created an extension (2001) which needs to do the following:
1) Check which of the 10 extensions is on a call
2) Be able to say a message that both party will hear on all busy extensions
3) As admin I do not want to hear what they are saying on the live calls

Overall, as admin I will call 2001 which will enable me to say a message to all active calls but I do not want to hear what they say on the phone

It is important that that the message will be received by all extensions AT THE SAME TIME

Can I achieve this in asterisk? I can build an AGI script if needed but I need some guidance

**UPDATE**

```
;Anyone who dials out with 9 can be spied later on
exten => _90XXXXXXXX.,1,Noop();whatever starts with nine
    same => n,Set(SPYGROUP=8005)       
    same => n(dial),Dial(SIP/${EXTEN:1}@mytrunck)
    same => n,Hangup()

;Spy exten dialed with 9
exten => 8008,1,NoOp()
    same => n,ChanSpy(,g(8005),qWB)
```

This is great for 1 person but it does not work for more than that

Can you please explain with an easy example how I can I put all of them in a conference?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.

Easy variant - create 10 two-way calls all to same conference, after that 1 call wich will play message to conference. Then kickall from that conf.

For channels which are on call you can use chanspy, for other channels use paging/intercom.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please give me a small example on how to achieve this? I have added an update to my question

Comment: No. Such "small example" will take 2-3 pages of text. Read plan above and try implement. Check this page http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+n-way+call+HOWTO